# How to Scraping Dynamic Website in Python Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm a finance student, very new to coding. I've been trying to learn Python for a week.

- Goal: 
  Scraping data for financial statements of listed companies  in Vietnam
  Source: https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/bang-can-doi-ke-toan/vnm.shtml?request_locale=en_GB (sample ticker: VNM)
- Situation: 
  I'm using Python 3 with BS4, Selenium for scraping and Pandas for tabling. I've read about Scrapy but I find it takes more efforts to learn.
- Problems:

  1. As you see, the website has drop-down menus for choosing years, number of terms, units...
     I've figured out the part of using Selenium to select options and click View button to load the data. 
     I have trouble getting the data afterward. I tried to use 'wait until' but there is no change in website elements.
  2. Moving to Income and CF Statement, the data was there when inspecting but missing in page source (using Chrome).

Thank you for any help.

```
import requests as rq
import bs4
import pandas as pd

# ticker = input('Ticker')
ticker = 'vnm'

url = 'https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/bang-can-doi-ke-toan/' + ticker + '.shtml'
res = rq.get(url)
web_text = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
content = web_text.select('.bordertd')

mod_content =[]
for x in content:
    mod_content.append(x.getText().strip())

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

table = list(chunks(mod_content, 5))
bsheet=pd.DataFrame(table)
print(bsheet)
```

I keep the part with Selenium separated:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome('path')
browser.get('https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/bang-can-doi-ke-toan/VNM.shtml')

dropdown = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("searchObject.fiscalQuarter"))
dropdown.select_by_value('IN_YEAR')
browser.find_element_by_class_name('iButton').click()

# wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
# element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,'searchObject.fiscalQuarter')))

content = browser.page_source
browser.quit()

content = web_text.select('.bordertd')
mod_content =[]
for x in content:
    mod_content.append(x.getText().strip())
mod_content
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is you code? Nobody will write your program instead of you. Please read how to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry, I posted my code. For the first problem, I tried some in https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Unless the website you are scraping uses complex javascript to render content, you probably don't need to overcomplicate things with Selenium. You can construct a session directly using the requests library, then pass whatever GET or POST (form) parameters you need.